# Is it possible to have an Office365 web app active in a nested browser control on an iOS app

Tags: ios, office365

I'm building an iPad app that connects to Office365 and brings down a list of all documents in a document library. I'd like to have a browser control embedded in my app that hosts the Office WebApp for the appropriate document to allow a document preview. For example, Id like to be able to select a Word document in the list and have the Word Web App open in an adjoining pane with the live document loaded (allowing editing, etc.). Is this possible? Or is there some sort of restriction to having an Office Web App running in an embedded browser window?

Answer (score 0):

Apps for Office in the browser
The Office Web Apps also host apps for Office and require a browser that supports HTML 5 and JavaScript 5, like:

Internet Explorer 9 with at least MS12-037: Cumulative Security Update for Internet Explorer: June 12, 2012 installed
Internet Explorer 10 or later (strongly recommended)
At least Mozilla Firefox 12
At least Apple Safari 5
At least Google Chrome 18

from:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/support/supported-browsers-in-office-2013-and-office-365-HA102789344.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but you didn't answer my question. I'm asking about embedding a browser window (showing an open office document) within an iPad app. I believe that I had read that office web apps can't be placed in a nested iFrame for security reasons (to prevent click-jacking, etc. I really want to know if there are any such restrictions in a nested browser control.